# SQL Function output as a list - Python

Tags: python

I have a function to query the data and return the output

```
import sqlite3
def viewdata(number):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("alpha.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT Alpha,beta,gamma, number FROM alphanum WHERE number=?"),(number,))
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return data
```

i want the values to be stored in a list so that the Alpha becomes the first value in that list, beta becomes the second value and gamma is the third so i did this

```
import sqlite3
def viewdata(number):
    data=[]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("alpha.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT Alpha,beta,gamma, number FROM alphanum WHERE number=?"),(number,))
    data.append(cursor.fetchall())
    conn.close()
    return data
```

it is not working as expected, it throws index out of range error if i use this function and try to fetch [1] value . How can i get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the list comprehension like this

```
def viewdata(number):
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("alpha.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(("SELECT Alpha,beta,gamma, number FROM alphanum WHERE number=?"),(number,))
data=[i for i in cursor.fetchall()]
conn.close()
return data
```

and while accessing the data i am using like this

```
viewdata(2)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the *list* but rather the *nested tuple*.

You have something like

```
data = [(('f00', 1, 'bla'), (...))]
```

So you cannot do `data[1]`.

Instead of `.append()`, use

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

and do not initialize it (`data = []`), there is no need for that.

Comment: This is what is there in the first code of my question

Comment: @Python_newbie You are not making sense then I am afraid. Why do you think that the list will affect the order of the values inside:?

Comment: Please see clearly the code which i have as first in my question is what you have given here

Comment: @Python_newbie Your problem description does not make sense. The order of Alpha, Beta, etc has nothing to do with `list` vs `tuple` and nothing to do with the Error you are getting.. These are 3 different things.